# Why does `Let` add a newline? (And can I get rid of it?)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In my shell I was trying some things and noticed and added newline at the beginning of my `let` statement.

```
[86]> (setf A 5)
5
[87]> (let () (print 'hello) (print 'there) A )
       ;; this blank line right here
HELLO
THERE
5
```

Is there a was to remove the extra newline?

Answer (score 7):

It's not `let` that's adding the newline --- it's `print`.

According to [the CLHS](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_writecm_p_rintcm_princ.html): "print is just like prin1 except that the printed representation of object is **preceded by a newline** and followed by a space."

You *could* use `prin1` instead:

```lisp
CL-USER> (let () (prin1 'hello) (print 'there) 5)
HELLO
THERE 
5
```

or you could use `format`

```lisp
CL-USER> (let () (format t "~a~%~a~%" 'hello 'there) 5)
HELLO
THERE
5
```